# wp_nav_menu : Give lowest children the url of the parent + extra variable

Tags: wordpress, menu, menuitem, submenu

I want to create the following for a wordpress menu:

for example I have this menu:

1. Parent (page_id=1)

   - 1 Child (page_id=2)
   - 2 Child (page_id=3)
   - 3 Child (page_id=4)
2. Parent (page_id=5)

   - 1 Child (page_id=6)

     - 1 Child (page_id=7)
     - 2 Child (page_id=8)
3. Parent (page_id=9)
4. Parent (page_id=10)

What I want:
Change the url of the lowest child to the child or parent above, and add a extra custom variable to the child url.

Finally, the menu has to become like this: (data-page-id is my custom variable)

1. Parent (page_id=1)

   - 1 Child (page_id=1&data-page-id=2)
   - 2 Child (page_id=1&data-page-id=3)
   - 3 Child (page_id=1&data-page-id=4)
2. Parent (page_id=5)

   - Child (page_id=6)

     - 1 Child (page_id=6&data-page-id=7)
     - 2 Child (page_id=6&data-page-id=8)
3. Parent (page_id=9)
4. Parent (page_id=10)

How to get this working? Is it also possibible to apply this to one menu only (created in wp-admin)?

Comment: Nobody who knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can alter the rendering of menu with nav menu walker. review the link, override the walker_nav_menu

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116708/customizing-walker-nav-menu

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src//wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L0

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how to check if it's the last child and get the parent of the last child?